# Should I edit my answer after an edit/clarification to the question?

Tags: discussion

This is just an example, but here: [Chain Puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29497/join-six-five-link-chains-to-form-a-circular-chain)

The original question did not stipulate the required length of the chain. With a bit of abuse to this I answered as can be seen in the question. (TL;DR - hook all the chains together through a single set of links).

**My question is:** What is the appropriate action for an answerer to take once the OP has changed/clarified the original question? 
 In the aforementioned example, I edited my post to clearly indicate that my answer was for a previous incarnation and was no longer technically valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@goodguy5 What you did in the example is generally considered acceptable. Add to your answer saying EDIT:

And where your answer id to the original question, add the original question itself so it will be clear this is not your answer and is correct for the original post.

Comment: I was hoping for a bit more attention to this, but thank you for your answer.